# Javascript,Dialog Box,Database

Tags: javascript, database, web, modal-dialog

The code below is an example from the following link :
http://bootboxjs.com/examples.html

Example Name: Custom HTML Forms

```
bootbox.dialog({
                title: "This is a form in a modal.",
                message: '<div class="row">  ' +
                    '<div class="col-md-12"> ' +
                    '<form class="form-horizontal"> ' +
                    '<div class="form-group"> ' +
                    '<label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="name">Name</label> ' +
                    '<div class="col-md-4"> ' +
                    '<input id="name" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Your name" class="form-control input-md"> ' +
                    '<span class="help-block">Here goes your name</span> </div> ' +
                    '</div> ' +
                    '<div class="form-group"> ' +
                    '<label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="awesomeness">How awesome is this?</label> ' +
                    '<div class="col-md-4"> <div class="radio"> <label for="awesomeness-0"> ' +
                    '<input type="radio" name="awesomeness" id="awesomeness-0" value="Really awesome" checked="checked"> ' +
                    'Really awesome </label> ' +
                    '</div><div class="radio"> <label for="awesomeness-1"> ' +
                    '<input type="radio" name="awesomeness" id="awesomeness-1" value="Super awesome"> Super awesome </label> ' +
                    '</div> ' +
                    '</div> </div>' +
                    '</form> </div>  </div>',
                buttons: {
                    success: {
                        label: "Save",
                        className: "btn-success",
                        callback: function () {
                            var name = $('#name').val();
                            var answer = $("input[name='awesomeness']:checked").val()
                            Example.show("Hello " + name + ". You've chosen <b>" + answer + "</b>");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        );
```

I would like to know how to send the data entered in the textbox to a particular column and a particular row(based on condition) to a database to overwrite the data of the column for the particular row when the user clicks on the "save" button.

Please give me details on whether I can use javascript to do this and if not, which language should I use. Moreover, please also tell me how to do it by giving me the code using this example given above.

I have just started on web development and I don't have much experience. I would be very thankful to you if you can give me a good answer and solve my problem. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Well, you already handle the data within your success part don't you? your "callback" section is not working...? :)

Comment: about your database work, if you want to do it with javascript then you need some ajax. ($.ajax)...

Comment: Hi Julo0s . Can you clarify what u mean. Thanks a lot - Julo0s !

Comment: Hi Julo0s - I need ajax - ok

Comment: Hi Julo0s - can u give me the ajax code to do it with explanation as I am a beginner. It would be very much appreciated. Thank you - Julo0S !

Comment: What you are describing is essentially any database backed app. There are probably a million different ways to accomplish this in javascript alone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, don't know if you really understand what you are doing, then you should have a look at this part in your code :

```
//This is the part where you are supposed to handle your data
//This code is called only when you click on your success button
callback: function () {
    var name = $('#name').val();
    var answer = $("input[name='awesomeness']:checked").val()
    Example.show("Hello " + name + ". You've chosen <b>" + answer + "</b>");
}
```

So, if this code is good, you just have to do your database job there, a good way to do it may be an ajax call - function :

```
$.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    url : 'yourPhpCodeToWriteInDatabase.php',
    data : {'data1':something,'data2':somethingElse},
    error : function(response){
        //do something if your php code fails
    },
    success : function(response){
        //do something if your php code succeeds
    }
});
```

Maybe surrounding your .ajax code into a function with a callback you call only on success would be good too... like this :

```
function writeToDatabase(data1,data2,callback){
    //your ajax code and error/success like this : 
    //...
    error : function(response){
        callback(response);
    },
    success : function(response){
        callback(response);
    }
    //...
}
```

Then, in your code (your bootbox...) in the callback part do something like this :

```
//...
callback : function(){
    writeToDatabase($('#name').val(),$("input[name='awesomeness']:checked").val(),function(response){
        //do something with the function response there!
    });
}
//...
```

**This is only one way to do it. I don't pretend this is the best way to do the job, but this may be a solution. You should maybe wait for other people to show you another way to do it, that would maybe fit better your problem. But here is a way to go.**

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you very much. Julo0sS - I will try it and ask if I have any questions.